# memory_profiler: how to plot per-function memory usage

Tags: python, memory-profiling

version: 0.50.0

In the [official documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler). there is a link to this [blog](http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2014/plot-memory-usage-as-a-function-of-time/) which give me instruction of how to make per-function memory usage plot. but when I try to run the exactly code in this post.

test1.py

```
import time

@profile
def test1():
    n = 10000
    a = [1] * n
    time.sleep(1)
    return a

@profile
def test2():
    n = 100000
    b = [1] * n
    time.sleep(1)
    return b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test1()
    test2()
```

command is:

```
mprof run test1.py
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "test.py", line 3, in 
>       @profile
>   NameError: name 'profile' is not defined

this is very strange, because there is the quotes from official :

> Warning
>
> If your Python file imports the memory profiler from memory_profiler import profile these timestamps will not be recorded. Comment out the import, leave your functions decorated, and re-run.

So if I want to have the per-function memory usage plot, I need comment out  `from memory_profiler import profile`, but when I comment out it, there is a error.

Comment: This is a bug in v0.50, and should be fixed in the current v0.51

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Documentation is not really up-to-date, try with `mprof run --python python3 test1.py` (having import commented out), it seems to work for me, but generates output to file only and does not write to stdout at all.

Comment: thanks. it dows works. I also file a bug at github. I will share your answer, maybe can help them figure out the problem.

Comment: In case anyone come here with the same issue trying to run pytest, it works; Instead of `python3` use `pytest`
`mprof run --python pytest path_to_test_file`